# "Besides the fact that..."

Tags: expression

Gibt es einen deutschen Ausdruck, der diesen englischen entspricht? Meiner Einschätzung nach würde man sagen

> Außer der Tatsache, dass

aber für mich klingt das ziemlich unidiomatisch.

Comment: Manchmal geht einfach "außerdem"

Comment: @Ingo: Kannst Du ein Beispiel dafür geben? Ich wüsste nämlich gerade keines.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft *Besides from the fact that beer is healthy, it also tastes good.* - `Bier ist gesund. Außerdem schmeckt es gut.` oder zusammengefaßt: `Bier ist nicht nur gesund, es schmeckt außerdem noch gut.`

Comment: @Ingo: Dann verschiebst Du aber das Gewicht auf den ersten Teilsatz. In »A, außerdem B.« liegt das Gewicht auf A. – In »Besides the fact that A, B« liegt das Gewicht auf B.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Deshalb schrieb ich "manchmal", vor allem dann, wenn es gar nicht so sehr um Gewichte einzelner Sätze geht, sondern eher darum, eine Aufzählung nackter Tatsachen sprachlich etwas aufzubereiten.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> (Mal (ganz)) abgesehen davon, dass …

*Mal* (without *ganz*) is colloquial. *Mal ganz* is used, if you want to emphasise that the argument in the *besides* clause is powerful enough that anything that follows does not really matter:

> Mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass ich eh keine Zeit habe, würde ich lieber ins Theater als ins Kino gehen. –  Besides the fact that I have no time anyway, I would prefer to go to the theatre over going to the cinema.

Comment: I'd like to add that the "mal" is colloquial and the same is possible and more likely in writing without it...

Answer (score 1):

In gehobenem Schriftdeutsch gibt es noch die Wendung:

> **ungeachtet der Tatsache**, dass...

Beispiel:

> Nachdem der neue Behandlungsansatz sowie erste positive Erfahrungsberichte 2009 publik wurden, stürzten sich Patienten auf die Behandlungsmöglichkeit. Ungeachtet der Tatsache, dass es keine klinischen Studie dazu gab. <sup>[Spiegel online](http://www.spiegel.de/gesundheit/diagnose/multiple-sklerose-das-ende-der-cerebro-spinalen-nervoesen-insuffizienz-a-926863.html)</sup>

Comment: Ist das nicht eher ***despite** the fact?*